# No "New/Edit Item" option after migrating SharePoint List 2003 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-list, migration, 2003

Hi what should we need to configure on the manifest file of SharePoint List 2003 aside from setting Product Revision from version 3 to version 4.

Below is the missing option after uploading my 2003 .stp file.

[image]

Manifest.XML File:

```
<Details>
<TemplateDescription></TemplateDescription>
<TemplateTitle>Applications Inventory</TemplateTitle>
<ProductVersion>4</ProductVersion>
<Language>1033</Language>
<TemplateID>39</TemplateID>
<Configuration>0</Configuration>
<FeatureId>{00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100}</FeatureId>
<TemplateType>100</TemplateType>
<BaseType>0</BaseType>
</Details>
<Files>
<File Name="AllItems.aspx" Src="00000000.000">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:F548C95F-58F7-4298-9D91-EDF578B20854@00000000001" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{F548C95F-58F7-4298-9D91-EDF578B20854},1&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hasdefaultcontent" Value="BX|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_filesize" Value="IR|2649" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedhastheme" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_parserversion" Value="SR|12.0.0.6665" /><MetaKey Name="vti_modifiedby" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoreversion" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_charset" Value="SR|utf-8" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_linkinfo" Value="SW|URUS|~masterurl/default.master USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif UZUL|/_layouts/images/banners/ApplicationsInventory.jpg" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedzones" Value="VR|Main" /><MetaKey Name="vti_author" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_setuppath" Value="SX|pages\viewpage.aspx" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{F548C95F-58F7-4298-9D91-EDF578B20854}" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolversion" Value="SR|V1.0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolcookie" Value="SR|fp_internal" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedneedsrewrite" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_themeaggregate" Value="SR|default" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /></MetaInfo>
</File>
<Folder Name="Attachments">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_isexecutable" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:618CB26A-16BF-4C11-8E72-B37532DC0794@00000000000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{618CB26A-16BF-4C11-8E72-B37532DC0794},0&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_isbrowsable" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_isscriptable" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hassubdirs" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_dirlateststamp" Value="TW|19 Aug 2014 01:20:00 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{618CB26A-16BF-4C11-8E72-B37532DC0794}" /></MetaInfo>
</Folder>
<File Name="DispForm.aspx" Src="10000000.000">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:B68E69E1-4921-4E66-9880-82E02D7B6F6F@00000000001" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{B68E69E1-4921-4E66-9880-82E02D7B6F6F},1&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hasdefaultcontent" Value="BX|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_filesize" Value="IR|3188" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedhastheme" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_parserversion" Value="SR|12.0.0.6665" /><MetaKey Name="vti_modifiedby" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoreversion" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_charset" Value="SR|utf-8" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedzones" Value="VR|Main" /><MetaKey Name="vti_linkinfo" Value="VX|URUS|~masterurl/default.master USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif" /><MetaKey Name="vti_author" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_setuppath" Value="SX|pages\form.aspx" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{B68E69E1-4921-4E66-9880-82E02D7B6F6F}" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolversion" Value="SR|V1.0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolcookie" Value="SR|fp_internal" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedneedsrewrite" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_themeaggregate" Value="SR|default" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /></MetaInfo>
</File>
<File Name="EditForm.aspx" Src="20000000.000">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:3B99F8A5-BCDC-461F-A7FC-443A2F7DB77D@00000000001" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{3B99F8A5-BCDC-461F-A7FC-443A2F7DB77D},1&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hasdefaultcontent" Value="BX|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_filesize" Value="IR|3188" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedhastheme" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_parserversion" Value="SR|12.0.0.6665" /><MetaKey Name="vti_modifiedby" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoreversion" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_charset" Value="SR|utf-8" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedzones" Value="VR|Main" /><MetaKey Name="vti_linkinfo" Value="VX|URUS|~masterurl/default.master USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif" /><MetaKey Name="vti_author" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_setuppath" Value="SX|pages\form.aspx" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{3B99F8A5-BCDC-461F-A7FC-443A2F7DB77D}" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolversion" Value="SR|V1.0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolcookie" Value="SR|fp_internal" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedneedsrewrite" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_themeaggregate" Value="SR|default" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /></MetaInfo>
</File>
<Folder Name="Item">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_isexecutable" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:C69E7B2E-4739-4882-88F1-ABE75F0808FE@00000000000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{C69E7B2E-4739-4882-88F1-ABE75F0808FE},0&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_isbrowsable" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_isscriptable" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hassubdirs" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|10 Oct 2008 11:09:26 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_dirlateststamp" Value="TW|19 Aug 2014 01:20:00 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{C69E7B2E-4739-4882-88F1-ABE75F0808FE}" /></MetaInfo>
</Folder>
<File Name="NewForm.aspx" Src="30000000.000">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:4399ECBA-DA8E-4CE6-A4AC-1A34423333B7@00000000001" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{4399ECBA-DA8E-4CE6-A4AC-1A34423333B7},1&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hasdefaultcontent" Value="BX|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_filesize" Value="IR|3188" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedhastheme" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_parserversion" Value="SR|12.0.0.6665" /><MetaKey Name="vti_modifiedby" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoreversion" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_charset" Value="SR|utf-8" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|02 May 2013 08:06:50 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedzones" Value="VR|Main" /><MetaKey Name="vti_linkinfo" Value="VX|URUS|~masterurl/default.master USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif USUL|/_layouts/images/blank.gif" /><MetaKey Name="vti_author" Value="SR|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_setuppath" Value="SX|pages\form.aspx" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{4399ECBA-DA8E-4CE6-A4AC-1A34423333B7}" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolversion" Value="SR|V1.0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolcookie" Value="SR|fp_internal" /><MetaKey Name="vti_cachedneedsrewrite" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_themeaggregate" Value="SR|default" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /></MetaInfo>
</File>
</Files>
```

Anyone experience this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable SharePoint 2013 default Toolbar please make sure that the following web part properties are set:

- `Toolbar Type` (`List Views` group) is set to `Full ToolBar`
- `Server Render` (`Miscellaneous` group) is set to False

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vadim Gremyachev on what section on my 2003 Manifest File it is located? Thanks

Comment: Since Server Render is a new XLV property introduced in SharePoint 2013, it is not contained in Manifest file. Probably the easiest way to modify those properties  would be to update them in the migrated web part via UI (see the updated answer)

Comment: I'm now on Edit Page > Edit Web Part of the uploaded custom list 2003 and only Appearance,Layout and Advanced Tab is the available tabs how can i add it. That option is only avaialble on 2013 custom list. Thanks

Comment: I think it works :D i just check unchecked miscellaneous option on existing 2013 custom list and it applied to the 2003 custom list. :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, that's great! :)